# Is it possible to derive related signature?

Tags: signature

For example, the message is a json: `{name: john, age: 13}`, and is sealed with signature.

Now, is it possible to derive a signature for the new message: `john is less than 18` ?

I feel, to achieve that, the `less than` operator should be well-defined.

Any known research in this field?

Comment: You could probably do this with _functional signatures_ (in theory).

Comment: @SEJPM By `in theory', do you mean there is no readily available software library for that?

Comment: Indeed, it appears that [functional signatures can in theory be constructed](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/401) but I'm not aware of any actual software implementation (but then I also didn't search a lot).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea about how to do a signature that specifies a specific range (and which makes it easy to enlarge the range):

We will assume a bounded range for the 'age', say, 0 to 150 ($max$), and we assume that $\text{H}$ is a preimage-resistant hash function, and $\text{H}^k$ denotes $\text{H}$ iterated $k$ times.

Then, we have a signature that has several parts:

- The values $MinAge, MaxAge$
- The value $max = \text{H}^{MaxAge}( r_1 )$
- The value $min = \text{H}^{max-MinAge}( r_2 )$
- The values $\text{H}^{max}( r_1 ), \text{H}^{max}( r_2 )$
- The signature for $\text{H}^{max}( r_1 ), \text{H}^{max}{r_2}$, and the rest of the clause (`name: John`).

The above signature states that John's age is between MinAge and MaxAge; the original signer (who knows the age) can generate a signature with $MinAge = MaxAge = \text{John's real age}$

This signature can be verified by verifying that $\text{H}^{max - MaxAge}(max)$ matches the $\text{H}^{max}(r_1)$ value, that $\text{H}^{MinAge}(min)$ matches the $\text{H}^{max}(r_2)$ value, and that the signature verifies.

The range that this signature denotes can be enlarged; the MaxAge can be increased to $MaxAge'$ by updating the value $MaxAge$ and replacing the value $max$ by $\text{H}^{MaxAge' - MaxAge}(max)$.  Similarly, the MinAge can be decreased to $MinAge'$ updating the value $MinAge$ and replacing the value $min$ by $\text{H}^{MinAge - MinAge'}(min)$.  Note that the range cannot be decreased, because that would require generating a preimage of $\text{H}$, which we assume is infeasible.

Comment: As it stands the description asks you to perform $2^{255}$ evaluations of $H$ for a 256-bit hash, is that intentional or is there some down-mapping or variable-reuse happening here?

Comment: @SEJPM: I perform the evaluations on the possible values of $age$, which I assume has a limited range (151 possible values in my example...)

Comment: @poncho I don't quite get the description.  What is r1 and r2 here? What is the relation between two max-s, 0 to 150(max) and max = H^ MaxAge(r1).  And how does the overall approach relate to the case in my question? Thanks

Comment: @FunkyBaby: $r_1$ and $r_2$ are random values selected during the signature generation process.  As for what things are, the signature is a statement that $MinAge \le Age \le MaxAge$; max is the 'proof' that $Age \le MaxAge$ (or, at least the Age that the original signer had in mind); someone with a signature that states that MaxAge = 17 cannot come up with a signature that states MaxAge = 16; the signature gives him the value $X$ with $H^{133}(X) = H^{150}(r_1)$; however changing MaxAge=16 would require him to find a value $Y$ with $H^{134}(Y) = H^{150}(r_1)$, possibly $H(Y) = X$, he can't

Comment: @FunkyBaby: as to how it answers the question, the initial signer signs with MinAge=MaxAge=13; that is, John's age is 13.  Someone later can expand the range to MinAge=0, MaxAge=17; that is, John's age is somewhere between 0 and 17 - that is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: @poncho's proposal seems correct, but I should note that the explanation is a bit confusing :) At least, it contains a typo: in the second part of the signature ("The value =$H^{(_1)}$"), it should be a separate variable like "The value $X_{}=H^{(_1)}$". The point is it conflicts with variable $max$ which is a common parameter (e.g. 150). As far as I understand.